# Mysql alias and left join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 two tables.One table contains 2 user id (like fast user and second user) in a row. Another table contains user data (like user name).

How can I retrieve 2 user name using left join?? I would like to have sql query. How can I get that result in php ??

Thanks

Foysal

Comment: please give some data structures and show the data sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.fastuser, b.*,
        a.secondUser, c.*
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            on a.fastUser = b.userID
        LEFT JOIN table2 c
            on a.secondUser = c.userID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the same table twice and use different alias names for tables and user_name columns:

```
select u1.user_name as first_username,
       u2.user_name as second_username
from some_table t
left join user_table u1 on t.first_user_id = u1.user_id
left join user_table u2 on t.second_user_id = u2.user_id
```

Comment: Then how can I get these results in php?? like below

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


echo "Name: ".$row['name'];
echo " Age: ".$row['age'];

Comment: You can use `alias` names like `first_username` and `second_username`. Then you can use them like `$row['first_username']`. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Say Table1 contains user info :--id,id_c,email,age etc.

Table 2 contains user_name :--id,user_name

here id in table1 refers to id in table 1(for 1st user)
here id_c in table1 refers to id in table 2(for 2nd user)
Then query would be like

```
select a.user_name,b.user_name,u.email from Table1 as u
left join Table2 as a on u.id=a.id
left join Table2 as b on u.id_c=b.id
```

You can go through my blog-post for reference purpose

http://codebucket.co.in/for-mysql-savvy-multiple-joins-with-alias/